# Coffeescript Function Syntax

Tags: function, coffeescript

I'm brand new to Coffeescript and struggling on the syntax. Can anyone help me with how the following should be written in CS?

```
$("#getLocation").click(function() {
  $('#location-loading').show();
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(applyLocation);
  return false;
});

function applyLocation(location) {
  $('#LogLongitude').val(location.coords.longitude);
  $('#LogLatitude').val(location.coords.latitude);
  alert('Latitude:' + location.coords.latitude + ', Longitude: ' + location.coords.longitude + ', Accuracy: ' + location.coords.accuracy);
  $('#location-loading').hide();
}
```

I thought the following would work, but I am getting errors with calling the function and returning false (so I don't follow the link).

```
$('#getLocation').click ->
  $('#location-loading').show()
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(applyLocation)
  false

applyLocation = (location) ->
  $('#LogLongitude').val(location.coords.longitude)
  $('#LogLatitude').val(location.coords.latitude)
  alert('Latitude:' + location.coords.latitude + ', Longitude: ' + location.coords.longitude + ', Accuracy: ' + location.coords.accuracy)
  $('#location-loading').hide()
```

Comment: Use js2coffee.org for more help.

Comment: It turns out that code worked fine, but I forgot to include "jQuery ->" at the start of the file since I was using jQuery and I had a few tabs instead of spaces because of a copy/paste issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the `()` parethesis for simple function calling (not chained)
and put the string in the lower part into double-quota to be able to use the `#{}` syntax, 
but except that your code does look quite coffeeish already ;)

```
$('#getLocation').click ->
  $('#location-loading').show()
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition applyLocation
  false

applyLocation = (location) ->
  coords = location.coords
  $('#LogLongitude').val coords.longitude
  $('#LogLatitude').val coords.latitude
  alert "Latitude: #{coords.latitude}, 
         Longitude: #{coords.longitude}, 
         Accuracy: #{coords.accuracy}"
  $('#location-loading').hide()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips and cleaning up the code. Your code looks much cleaner. I've updated mine as your suggestion. Thanks. As mentioned in my comment above, my code actually worked after adding "jQuery ->" to the start of the file.